# Find whole word not part of word in javascript string search

Tags: javascript, regex, indexof

I am trying to check if 'selected' appears in 'sizerange'.  But at the moment it evaluates as true because XS is in the 'sizerange'.  I have the same problem with L and XL.

I think I need to use regex \b \b for beginning or end of the word but couldn't get it to work with the variable

```
var sizerange = 'XS M L XL';
    var selected = 'S'

    if(sizerange.indexOf(selected) == -1){
    $( this ).addClass('sold-out');
        } else {
    $( this ).addClass('in-stock');
    };
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can do `sizerange.split(" ").includes(selected)`

Comment: Is it important that `sizerange` is one string? Why not `const sizeRange = [ 'XS', 'M', 'L', 'XL' ]` -- note that you can convert your string into this using `String.split()`. Regex is great, but if you don't need it, don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest, split it into an array and use includes. (It would make more sense to store it as an array instead of a string)

```js
var sizerange = 'XS M L XL';
var selected = 'S'

if (sizerange.split(/\s/).includes(selected)) {
  console.log('in stock')
} else {
  console.log('sold out')
}
```

other option is reg exp using [boundaries](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5CbS%5Cb%2F)

```js
var sizerange = 'XS M L XL';
var selected = 'S'

var regexp = new RegExp("\\b" + selected + "\\b");

if (regexp.test(sizerange)) {
  console.log('in stock')
} else {
  console.log('sold out')
}
```

Comment: Thank you both answers were helpful !

Answer (score 0):

```
var sizerange = 'XS M L XL';
var arraySizes = sizerange.split(' ');
var selected = 'S'

if(!arraySizes.includes(selected)){
  $( this ).addClass('sold-out');
} else {
  $( this ).addClass('in-stock');
};
```